# How can we show a time different from system time in Bash prompt?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time, centos

I have system time in PDT timezone in my CentOS machine but I want my bash prompt to display IST time without changing the system time. How can I set my *PS* environment variable to do that?

Comment: How do you want it to look like? What is your current `PS1` value? You want to add the date on top your existing `PS1`? It is not clear

Comment: Yes, I wanted the data on top of my existing PS1.

Comment: Insightful question which fostered amazing answer. Thank you for posting this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PS1="[\$(TZ='Asia/Kolkata' date '+%F %T %Z') \u@\h \W]\n\$ "
```

`\$(TZ='Asia/Kolkata' date '+%F %T %Z')` returns current time in IST.

Ref.: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html